# Calc and \settocdepth break \tikzexternalize

Tags: tikz-pgf, memoir, calculations, tikz-external

This might well be the strangest TeX behaviour I've ever seen and that's saying a lot. The following really is a MWE as far as the header is concerned:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\settocdepth{subsection}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[view={45}{45}]
    \addplot3[surf,samples=20,domain=-1:1,domain y=-1:1]
        {1-exp(-x^2-y^2)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Take away either package `calc` or the `\settocdepth` definition and everything will be fine. When both are present, though, `pdflatex -shell-escape` will stop and the following will be in the output log:

```
! Undefined control sequence. \@calc@post@scan ...st@scan \else \def \calc@next 
                                                                               {\calc@error #1}\fi \fi \f...
l.14 \end{tikzpicture}
```

If I wanted to file a bug report, I wouldn't even know where :/ Does anybody else see this behaviour and can you tell what's causing it?

Comment: Isn't `\settocdepth` accepting primarily numbers?

Comment: @tohecz No, but while I was trying to cite to you from the `memoir` documentation I stumbled on "`\settocdepth` [...] can only be used after the preamble but may be used before calling the `\tableofcontents`." Uhm, thanks I guess :)

Comment: Indeed, if you move `\settocdepth` after `\begin{document}` there's no problem.

Comment: I don't get any errors at all. Using frozen TL12. Well, not quite right, but I don't get the error the OP is citing.

Comment: @daleif This is getting stranger and stranger.

Comment: If I move `\settocdepth` after `\tikzexternalize`, then I don't get any errors. It compiles. Haven't checked the output though. `\tikzexternalize` is a bit strange. It does not like `fixltx2e` either.

Comment: @daleif I played it safe and put the `\settocdepth` in `\AfterPreamble` as it should apparently be. But yeah, `\tikzexternalize` is strange. Now my document finally builds again and I find other graphics in the background of my externalized TikZ plots. I guess I'll just increase the TeX memory and be done with it :/

Comment: It shouldn't, it was an error in the manual. It works just fine, placed in the manual. I could not find any reason why it should not be added in the preamble, so no idea why that comment was added in the first place. I've removed it.

Comment: @daleif Oh, I didn't realise who I was talking to :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The package `calc` changed the commands `\setcounter` and friends to be fragile. So you have to make them robust. The example below uses `etoolbox` with `\robustify`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\setcounter
\robustify\addtocounter
\robustify\setlength
\robustify\addtolength

\settocdepth{subsection}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize




\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[view={45}{45}]
    \addplot3[surf,samples=20,domain=-1:1,domain y=-1:1]
        {1-exp(-x^2-y^2)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

---

Normally there is no need for `calc`. Instead you should work with the etex commands `\dimexpr` or `numexpr`. This avoids such unwanted behaviour.

Comment: By why does that interfere with `externalize`?

Comment: @daleif: Good question ;-)

Comment: @daleif: In the "graphic generation run" externalize throws everything away that is in the document body but (naturally) keeps the preamble. `\settocdepth` in the preamble calls an `\addtocontents` which is not ignored in this run and executed in the (special) `\shipout` of externalize where the fragile `\setcounter` breaks.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Great.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer then why does it seem to work when we move `\settocdepth` after `\tikzexternalize`?

Answer (score 1):

The `\settocdepth{subsection}` must go after the `\tikzexternalize`. The `\AfterPreamble` macro from the `etoolbox` package is useful to prevent any such cases if `\settocdepth` is used in a package or document class, even though the advise from the memoir manual, not to use `\settocdepth` in the preamble at all is now obsolete.

Comment: It can be used just fine in the preamble. Not quite sure what goes wrong with `pdfplots` and `external` in this case.