# abntex2 does not accept tikzexternalize

Tags: tikz-pgf, abnt, externalize

I am using abntex2 to write my thesis and using several tikz pictures, which leads to long compiling times.

However, I am unable to use tikzexternalize with this document class.

The system is running Ubuntu 18.04 with Texlive. It has been used to compile other documents using tikzexternalize without problems.

Texmaker is issuing the command:

```
latex --shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

A clean code that is able to reproduce my error is:

```
\documentclass{abntex2}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{width=15cm,compat=1.9} 
\usetikzlibrary{external}

\tikzexternalize[optimize command away=\includepdf]

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[!ht]
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}
                    \addplot [samples=500,domain=0:2*pi,line width=0.5pt, black] {sin(deg(x))};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I have tried solutions posted on stackexchange without success.

The document compiles without any problem if the line "\tikzexternalize[optimize command away=\includepdf]" is commented out.

Comment: I confirm that the proposed modification does in did compile. However, it does not externalize the graphics.
If you change the \documentclass to article or memoir the initial code compiles and generates a separate PDF with the figure, which is the desired objective.

Comment: You are right. Sorry.

Comment: Perhaps you want to have a look at [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/183979/121799).

Comment: Is, my initial attempt did not work due to a typo.
Thanks for your help.
Should I delete this question since it is similar to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/183979/121799) previews question, as pointed out by marmot?